# Send AJAX request by clicking a link inside a dynamically created bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamically created accordion like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

   <div class="panel panel-default" >
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h5 class="panel-title small">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#1" class="tasktitle" data-id="1" id="opentask">$name</a>
         </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">body text</div>
      </div>

   <div class="panel panel-default" >
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h5 class="panel-title small">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#2" class="tasktitle" data-id="2" id="opentask">$name</a>
         </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">body text</div>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a static value like **$loggeduser** which is always the same for the logged user.

As this is a dynamically created accordion though, the id of each accordion section is different

What I am trying to achieve is when the user click to open the accordion, in the same time to execute an AJAX request which will send the value of the **$loggeduser** together with the id of the accordion in which the clicked link is placed in.

This is the ajax I am using to send the info to the file

```
$(function(){    
   $("#opentask").click(function(){
      $.get("markread-task.php?id=ID&user=LOGGEDUSERCOMMENT",function(data){
     });
   });
  return false;    
});
```

but I cant figure out how to to have a different ID in this link

```
markread-task.php?id=ID&user=LOGGEDUSERCOMMENT
```

for example if the user click on the link that opend accordion 2, the ajax sends link like

```
markread-task.php?id=2&user=LOGGEDUSERCOMMENT
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: We would need more code in order to help you here, there could be many possible solutions depending on how it's implemented.

Comment: what else do you need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Id must be unique to each element. Use class or name instead. So you cannot have two elements with id="opentask".

To get data-id value in your click method:

```
$(function(){    
   $(".opentask").click(function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $.get("markread-task.php?id="+id+"&user=LOGGEDUSERCOMMENT",function(data){
     });
   });
  return false;    
});
```

Comment: I would suggest that a pseudo class be used to get round the unique id. e.g. `$(".tasktitle").click(function(){ ......`

Comment: @maximelian1986, I have tried that,but it doesn't work

Comment: @Steve, I have tried that too, but still doesn't work

Comment: @maximelian1986, It worked actually. I was passing the wrong id so, didn't work at that time.